# Need Func to supply to Where() method of both IEnumerable and IQueryable

Tags: c#, linq, functional-programming, specification-pattern

I have a Func defined as follows:

```
Func<Foo, bool> IsSuperhero = x => x.WearsUnderpantsOutsideTrousers;
```

I can query IEnumerables like this:

```
IEnumerable<Foo> foos = GetAllMyFoos();
var superFoos = foos.Where(IsSuperhero);
```

But when I try to supply the same Func to the Where method of an IQueryable, I get:

'Cannot convert source type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable to System.Linq.IQueryable.'

What's going on? How can I define a Func which will work as a specification for both IEnumerable and IQueryable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IQueryable`'s LINQ methods take [Expression Trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx), not normal delegates.

Therefore, you need to change your `func` variable to an `Expression<Func<Foo, bool>>`, like this:

```
Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> IsSuperhero = x => x.WearsUnderpantsOutsideTrousers;
```

To use the same variable with an `IEnumerable<T>`, you'll need to call `AsQueryable()` or `Compile()`, like this:

```
IQueryable<Foo> superFoos = foos.AsQueryable().Where(IsSuperhero);
IEnumerable<Foo> superFoos = foos.Where(IsSuperhero.Compile());
```

Comment: But then I can't query IEnumerables with it!!! Surely there must be a way I can use the same specification with both?

Comment: @David: This behavior is necessary.  `IQueryable` is meant for things like LINQ to SQL, which need to find out what the delegate does.  This is not possible with a normal delegate, so they must take an `Expression<T>`.

Comment: Wow! I think I'm a long way from understanding that, but thanks for the pointer! :)

Comment: @David, it's worth learning more about, as expression trees are very, very cool.  They encode information about what the expression _means_ rather than simply resulting in code that performs the function.  Systems can make good use of this information to do fun, clever things like turning a strongly-typed .NET expression into a standard SQL query.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm aware that they are used to convert a set of criteria into another form (e.g. a SQL or LDAP query), but way in which this is done is, for me, in a distant, misty land full of magic. But that may not always be the case!